# NHibernate sub sub class property query

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

I have a class `A` which contains a class `B` which contains a class `C` with a property `P`. So something like this should work shouldn't it?:

```
var query = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(A));
query.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike(
              Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String,
                               Projections.Property("B.C.P")),
              "%bla%", MatchMode.Exact));
```

I get a `could not resolve property` exception.

I understand that I can use `CreateAlias` etc., which I have also tried with no avail. At the moment I opted for an 'implicit association join'.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateAlias (or CreateCriteria) is the only way to do it.

```
var query = Session.CreateCriteria<A>()
                   .CreateAlias("B", "B")
                   .CreateAlias("B.C", "C");
query.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike(
              Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String,
                               Projections.Property("C.P")),
              "%bla%", MatchMode.Exact));
```

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this. Just realised that 'implicit association joining' is only available for HQL. I guess that's my problem ...

Comment: Indeed. But you should also consider using HQL for this, unless your query is highly dynamic (i.e. based on independent filters that might or be used or not, changing sort orders, etc)

Comment: My query is very dynamic. That's why I needed this. Thanks!

Comment: BTW all NHibernate books I am aware of (inlcuding the online doc) only provide very simple query examples. Is there a good source/book for more advanced queries like this? Thanks!